# Franchisee for Stack Exchange

Tags: support, stack-exchange

If I have a good idea on Q and A for specific topic then can I get entire software, from Stack Exchange, for setting up my Q and A site? This may be a franchisee model (revenue sharing).

Answer (score 9):

Said on : https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/

> Q: I am interested in licensing the Stack Overflow source code.
>
> As a part of our new focus on serving large, internet-sized communities, we are no longer offering the Stack Overflow software.

By the way you can still make your proposal on the staging area of SE which is [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)